# Bash Parameter Expansion - get immediate parent directory of file

Tags: bash, shell, parameter-expansion

I'd like to get the name of the immediate parent directory of a given file, e.g. `foo` given `/home/blah/foo/bar.txt`, using a parameter expansion. Right now I can do it in two lines:

```
f="/home/blah/foo/bar.txt"
dir_name="${f%/*}"
immediate_parent="${dir_name##*/}"
```

But I'm very new to parameter expansions, so I assume this could be optimized. Is there a way to do it in only one line?

Comment: @j.a. It's a near-duplicate in that this question focuses on if and how the same problem can be solved using a specific feature, namely parameter expansion, even though the answer happens to be: "can't be done", and even though my answer here by happenstance ended up using essentially the same approach as your answer to the linked question. The value of this post is in showing _why_ it cannot (reasonably) be done _with parameter expansion_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with a single parameter expansion, but you can use `=~`, Bash's regex-matching operator:

```
[[ $f =~ ^.*/(.+)/.+$ ]] && immediate_parent=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

<sup>Note: Assumes an absolute path with at least 2 components.</sup>

If calling an external utility is acceptable, `awk` offers a potentially simpler alternative:

```
immediate_parent=$(awk -F/ '{ print $(NF-1) }' <<<"$f")
```

---

As for ***why* it can't be done** with a single parameter expansion:

- Parameter expansion allows for stripping ***either* a prefix** (`#` / `##`) ***or* a suffix** (`%` / `%%`) from a variable value, but **not both**.

  - *Nesting* prefix- and suffix-trimming expansions, while supported in principle, does not help, because you'd need iterative *modification* of values, whereas an expansion only ever *returns* the modified string; in other words: the effective *overall* expansion still only performs a *single* expansion operation, and you're again stuck with *either* a prefix *or* a suffix operation.
- Using a single parameter expansion, **extracting an *inner* substring can only be done by *character position and length***; e.g., a hard-coded solution based on the sample input would be: `immediate_parent=${f:11:3}`

  - You *can* use arithmetic expressions and even command substitutions as parameter expansion arguments, but the pointlessness of this approach - at least in this scenario - becomes obvious if we try it; note the embedded command substitutions - the first to calculate the character position, the second to calculate the length:

    ```
    immediate_parent=${f:$(d=${f%/*/*}; printf %s ${#d})+1:$(awk -F/ '{ print length($(NF-1)) }' <<<"$f")}
    ```